How does Facebook know where I'm from when using a clean machine
I'm currently using a library computer in a midwestern state that I do not live in. I'm originally from a west coast US city. I opened facebook marketplace (for which I was not signed into, nor have I ever been signed into on this machine) and it was immediately centered on the west coast city I am from. I am using Firefox with privacy settings set to "strict", Privacy Badger, Duckduckgo and Noscript extensions.
I don't believe they could have pulled an IP as I am not in my home city and not using a machine that has ever been in that city. I've had this laptop checked out for a few days, so I do have a search history, but I haven't searched anything directly related to my home city, and several things related to the city I'm currently in, so I don't think that's where the data came from.
The only way I can think they may have been able to pin me is that I signed into a google account (in chrome, a different browser than I did the facebook search on) on the same machine, however I have all my privacy settings as strict as possible on there.
At this point I'm not even mad, I'm just impressed and a bit frightened. I thought I was doing everything to keep a low profile but apparently I missed something. Any insights would be appreciated.

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  I was the one who closed this so I'm adding it to the reopen-review queue to allow the community a chance to do its own review and decide if it should remain closed or be reopened.
